# Change password LDAP Java

Tags: java, ldap, tivoli

I need to make an method to change an user password that is in the IBM TDS, i have to compare the if the user provide the correct user password, and change it. i have the username, oldpassword and newpassword as parameters.
Anyone knows how to make it?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [UnboundID LDAP SDK](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldapsdk/).

- The BIND request will verify whether the existing password is correct - there is no need to compare passwords, the BIND request will return a result code of zero if the password matches the password stored in the directory server database
- Use either the modify operation or the password modify extended request to change the password

#### see also

- [Password modify extended request](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/11/12/ldap-password-modify-extended-request/)